# PHP preg regular expression pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

1. What does this pattern `'/\\\(?!&amp;#|\?#)/'` match in PHP preg_replace function?
2. Is this pattern valid?
3. Why there are 3 backslashes in a row `\\\`?

Comment: This pattern is not valid ``/\\\(?!&amp;#|\?#)/``, as it contains ``ODD`` number of ``\`` char.

Comment: @deceze No, it's from sanitizing function.

Comment: @Cylian `'/\\\(?!&amp;#|\?#)/'` is valid though. Note the `'`.

Comment: @Cylian It should be 4 ` \ ` in this case, right?

Comment: @deceze If it's valid what ` \\\ ` means in this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The pattern checks for a literal backslash *not* followed by `&amp;#` or `?#`.
2. Yes.
3. Because it's written as a PHP string literal. `'\\'` (an escaped escape character) in a string literal resolves to the actual string `'\'`, so the actual regular expression is `/\\(?!&amp;#|\?#)/`. The backslash is escaped inside the regex so it does not escape the `(`. So the actual pattern looked for is `\&amp;#` or `\?#`.